# Obfuscate Java JAR-file with imported classes

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, proguard

I want to obfuscate and optimize a Java JAR-file using ProGuard.
The JAR-file is a collection of self-written classes and imported classes for JDBC and SQLite.

The imported classes does not have to be obfuscated but maybe optimized. It would be nice to to be have one configuration that obfuscate all and optimize all and one configuration that just optimize and obfuscate my code and leave the imported classes untouched.

I have done some research and tried different configurations to achieve this but failed, ProGuard displays many warnings and several errors and my attempts changing the script has no or little effect.

I develop in Eclipse and use an Ant `build.xml` file to do the work.

Does someone know how this should be done?

**This is my Ant build file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="Ant-ProGuard-Build" default="main" basedir=".">
<!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
<!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
<property name="src.dir" location="src" />
<property name="build.dir" location="build" />
<property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
<property name="docs.dir" location="docs" />
<property name="lib.dir" location="lib" />

<!-- Define external resources -->
<taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties"
classpath="C:\eclipse\ProGuard-4.8\lib\proguard.jar" />


<target name="main" depends="compile, jar, obfuscate"
    description="Create project">
</target>


<echo>-== Creating project ==-</echo>

<!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
<target name="compile" description="Compile target">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
    </javac>
</target>


<!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\Myprogram_Ant.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="se.me.myprogram.main.ProgMain" />
        </manifest>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="./lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </jar>    
</target>


<target name="obfuscate" depends="compile, jar"
    description="Obfuscate compiled classes">
    <proguard>
        -libraryjars "${java.home}\lib\rt.jar"
        -libraryjars "${lib.dir}\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar"
        -libraryjars "${lib.dir}\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar"
        -injars      "${dist.dir}\StockWatch_Ant.jar"
        -outjars     "${dist.dir}\StockWatch_ProGuard.jar"


        # All entry points will be in this package
        -keep public class se.me.myprogram.main.*
        -keepclassmembers public class se.me.myprogram.main.ProgMain {
                    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
        }


        # Keep the imported classes public
        -keep public class com.mysql.**
        -keep public class org.**
    </proguard>
</target>


<echo>---------- Creation of project is done! ----------</echo>
```

**The errors I get is:**

```
    Buildfile: C:\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE\MyProgram\Ant_ProGuard_Build.xml
     [echo] -== Creating project ==-
     [echo] ---------- Creation of project is done! ----------
compile:
[javac] C:\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE\MyProgram\Ant_ProGuard_Build.xml:29: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
jar:
obfuscate:
 [proguard] ProGuard, version 4.8
 [proguard] Reading program jar [C:\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE\MyProgram\dist\MyProgram_Ant.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
 [proguard] Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester: can't find superclass or interface com.mchange.v2.c3p0.QueryConnectionTester
 [proguard] Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter: can't find superclass or interface org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
 [proguard] Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker: can't find superclass or interface org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.ValidConnectionChecker
 [proguard] Warning: org.sqlite.SQLite: can't find superclass or interface org.ibex.nestedvm.UnixRuntime
 [proguard] Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester: can't find referenced class com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0ProxyConnection
 [proguard] Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter: can't find referenced class org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
 [proguard] Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 .
 80 lines... with same message : "[proguard] Warning: ......: can't find referenced class ....."
 .
 [proguard] Warning: org.sqlite.SQLite: can't find referenced class org.ibex.nestedvm.Runtime$CPUState
 [proguard] Warning: org.sqlite.SQLite: can't find referenced class org.ibex.nestedvm.Runtime$CPUState
 [proguard] Note: com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError calls '(java.sql.SQLException)Class.forName(variable).newInstance()'
 [proguard] Note: com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement accesses a constructor '<init>(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement$CallableStatementParamInfo)' dynamically
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement { CallableStatement(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement$CallableStatementParamInfo); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4CallableStatement { JDBC4CallableStatement(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement$CallableStatementParamInfo); }'
 [proguard] Note: com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData accesses a constructor '<init>(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String)' dynamically
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData { DatabaseMetaData(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema { DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4DatabaseMetaData { JDBC4DatabaseMetaData(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema { JDBC4DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement { JDBC4PreparedStatement(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement { PreparedStatement(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl { StatementImpl(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard] Note: com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData accesses a constructor '<init>(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String)' dynamically
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData { DatabaseMetaData(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema { DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4DatabaseMetaData { JDBC4DatabaseMetaData(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema { JDBC4DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement { JDBC4PreparedStatement(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement { PreparedStatement(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl { StatementImpl(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard] Note: com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy accesses a constructor '<init>(com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy)' dynamically
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4LoadBalancedMySQLConnection { JDBC4LoadBalancedMySQLConnection(com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedMySQLConnection { LoadBalancedMySQLConnection(com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy); }'
 [proguard] Note: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement accesses a constructor '<init>(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String)' dynamically
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData { DatabaseMetaData(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema { DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4DatabaseMetaData { JDBC4DatabaseMetaData(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema { JDBC4DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement { JDBC4PreparedStatement(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement { PreparedStatement(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl { StatementImpl(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection,java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard] Note: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlPooledConnection accesses a constructor '<init>(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection)' dynamically
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.ProfilerEventHandlerFactory { ProfilerEventHandlerFactory(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4MysqlPooledConnection { JDBC4MysqlPooledConnection(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlPooledConnection { MysqlPooledConnection(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection); }'
 [proguard] Note: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.SuspendableXAConnection accesses a constructor '<init>(com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl)' dynamically
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl$10 { ConnectionImpl$10(com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4SuspendableXAConnection { JDBC4SuspendableXAConnection(com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.SuspendableXAConnection { SuspendableXAConnection(com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl); }'
 [proguard] Note: com.mysql.jdbc.log.LogFactory accesses a constructor '<init>(java.lang.String)' dynamically
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionGroup { ConnectionGroup(java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.EscapeTokenizer { EscapeTokenizer(java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.mysql.jdbc.MiniAdmin { MiniAdmin(java.lang.String); }'
 .
 .
 .
 1040 lines... with same message : "[proguard]       Maybe this is program method....."
 .
 .
 .
 [proguard]       Maybe this is library method 'sun.util.locale.LocaleSyntaxException { LocaleSyntaxException(java.lang.String); }'
 [proguard] Note: there were 1 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
 [proguard]       You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
 [proguard]       their implementations (using '-keep').
 [proguard] Note: there were 8 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
 [proguard]       You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
 [proguard]       (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
 [proguard] Warning: there were 50 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
 [proguard] Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.
 [proguard]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
 [proguard]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
 [proguard]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
 [proguard]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.

BUILD FAILED
C:\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE\MyProgram\Ant_ProGuard_Build.xml:49: Please correct the above warnings first.

Total time: 7 seconds
```

Comment: How do I do that? I have tested : -libraryjars for both my external jars, but it doesn't help.

Comment: It does not help if I uncomment the lines :

Comment: The lines were commented by misstace, the log of errors is with the -libraryjars uncommented, as I have corrected now.

Comment: What are those files (slf4j.jar and c3p0-xxx.jar)? The only two jar-files I use is : mysql-connector-xxx.jar and sqlite-jdbc-xxx.jar, and those two are the only files in "lib".

Comment: Yes, it allows folders I have now tried : -libraryjars "${java.home}\lib\". With that I got even more errors about 50 "Maybe this is library method" and 108 more "Note: duplicate definition of library class", but none of the existing were solved.

Comment: How do you do that, and what is KM?